# Do we perform text embedding before or after train-test splitting?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, embeddings

Do we perform text embedding before or after train-test splitting?

I know that for encoding variables, usually done after the split. However, I'm not sure if that's also the case for text processing?

Comment: A practical rule of thumb is that, during your analysis, you should treat your validation/test data as if they were not even available at the time; so, split immediately and before any analysis stage (including text embedding).

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut, so how about embedding a field with fixed # categories? i.e. it's impossible to have new OOV on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute embeddings after the split, otherwise you would be  incurring in data leakage and *hiding* the out-of-vocabulary word problem.

Comment: Thank you @noe for your answering. One follow up question: if for example I've a categorical field containing x catgories in total. And I'm pretty sure there won't be any OOV for categories as they are all the fixed forever categories. Now in this case, I can embed the whole dataset on this tiny field?

Comment: I think that if you are encoding a categorical variable in an embedding, you would do so as part of the training in a specific task (i.e. classification), where there are other input variables apart form the category. If that is the case, note that the final embeddings would not only depend on the categorical variable, but also on the other variables. Therefore, you anyway must split before anything. I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, though.

Comment: thank you for the answering. Yes you're right there would be other variables as well. But given I know that category would be fixed, can I embed only that column on whole dataset and leave the rest of processing done after split?